# ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll doesn't trigger for some people

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook which refreshes data on startup. After the refresh is finished the rows which don't contain data are being hidden. The refresh is started when a worksheet is activated. I've added the same code in a Before_Print function to ensure the data has had enough time to load. The data is coming from a SQL Server database. But these problems have also existed when I was using Access as a backend.

For 9 out of 10 people the code I have written works. For the people from who it doens't work there happens nothing on startup. The entire 'ThisWorkbook' doesn't seem to be working for them. I think it's due to some difference in settings or something. What could be the problem here? These people have macro's enabled

Here the code which triggers when the worksheet is activated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

Dim r As Range, c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set r = Range("H99:H142")
For Each c In r
    If Len(c) = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The code that tirggers this on startup:

```
Private Sub RefreshSheet()
  Worksheets("-").Activate
  Worksheets("DPM").Activate
End Sub

Sub Workbook_Activate()
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "ThisWorkbook.RefreshSheet"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just to be sure, these people have macro's enabled?

Comment: Have you debugged to see which events are and aren't called?

Comment: @JvdV Yes they have macro's enables. I've set all external data settings to accept all sources.

Comment: See [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) from Chip Pearson for steps you can take to help figure out what's going on, by *stepping* through the code and checking the variable values as you go.

Comment: @DennisvdEijnde just to clarify, what 'user' is talking about has nothing to do with external data settings.  Regardless, the problem will be much more clear when you step through the code to figure out which parts are getting missed and why.  (Or do you already know exactly which lines are being missed?)

Comment: @user7393973 I haven't done that but I base the ThisWorkbook module not working on the fact that the code for not asking to save the workbook also doens't work for them

Comment: Is *any* of your code running on those machines?

Comment: Is *any* of your code running on those machines?

Comment: @ashleedawg If you mean that they run it on their computer then yes

Comment: @DennisvdEijnde Try adding a `Stop` statement at the start of `Workbook_Open` and see what goes wrong step by step.

Comment: Sorry guys... The people for who the code didn't work had their 'Enable content' messages disabled. This is why I assumed marcro's where enabled. Re-enabeling the messages and enabeling the content made it work.